Old animated Easter Bunny holiday movie for kids
As far as I can remember, this was an animated (claymation?) movie about a lazy Easter bunny who somehow gets himself into a contest with an evil rabbit. (The contest revolves around who can give out the most eggs before Easter is over.) The "good" bunny loses because he sleeps through Easter & thus ends up not giving out any eggs. (Bad guy bunny only manages to give away one egg - to a sleeping bloke - because he's scary-looking, but one is more than none, so he wins.)
In any case, the good bunny has to go back in time (or something) and attempt to give out eggs on other holidays in order to win. (He attempts things like painting the eggs green for St. Patrick's Day in order to get people to take them.) The more I try to describe this movie, the weirder/more ridiculous it sounds, but it's bugging me that I can't remember the name.

It was called Here Comes Peter Cottontail, a Rankin & Bass from 1971.

When the Chief Easter Bunny retires, he chooses Peter Cottontail as his successor. However, the reclusive January Q. Irontail wants the position as well, seeking to revenge himself upon children everywhere for the destruction of his tail. He proposes he and Peter have a race to see who can deliver the most eggs. Due to his own carelessness and Irontail's meddling, Peter oversleeps and loses the job. Luckily, a strange man and a worm give him access to a time machine, so Peter can set things right.




